# Div onclick event not called in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in my code:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div id="22" class="otherClass" onclick="goToEdit();">Title</div>
    <div class="parent">Other title</div>
</div>
```

And:

```
function goToEdit()
{
    tree.selectItem($(event.target).attr('id'));
    btnMyButton_onclick();
}
```

In Chrome everything works fine, but in Mozilla it doesn't react to the click event. Why?

Comment: How do you know that the event was not fired in Firefox (Mozilla)? Try putting an alert() in the function goToEdit()

Comment: What is `tree`? Does it refer to `window.tree` which in turn refers to an element with ID `tree`? If yes, Firefox does not create symbols in global scope for elements with IDs. You'd have to use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Sparky: Or better yet, using a proper debugger (Firefox has one built in now, or of course there's Firebug) and a breakpoint.

Comment: @FelixKling No, it is dhtmlx tree. I get error that event is not defined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I get error that event is not defined.

Comment: Ah yeah... in Firefox, the event object is passed as first argument to the event handler. You'd have to do `onclick="goToEdit(event);"` and `function goToEdit(event)`. That's like the 101 in event handling ;) To learn more about it, have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get error that event is not defined

**Doh!** We should all have realized.

The thing is that `event` is not a global on most browsers, though it is on IE and Chrome throws a bone to sites designed for IE by making it global as well as doing what it should do (passing it into the event handler function).

Your best bet by far is to not use `onclick="code"` at all (see below), but you can also do this:

```
<div id="22" class="otherClass" onclick="goToEdit(event);">Title</div>
```

...which should work cross-browser. It works because the `event` object is defined in the special context in which `onclick` handlers are called (on browsers that do this in a standard way), or it's a global (on IE), and so either way it's defined at that point (but not necessarily, as a global, later in your `goToEdit` function — which is why we pass it in as an argument).

But again, I wouldn't do that. Instead, I'd make the `id` value valid for CSS by having it start with a letter, and use jQuery to hook up the handler:

HTML:

```
<div id="d22" class="otherClass">Title</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#d22").click(goToEdit);
function goToEdit(event) {
    tree.selectItem(event.target.id.substring(1));
    btnMyButton_onclick();
}
```

Notes:

- I striped the `d` off the beginning of the `id` value before passing it on. I assume it was `22` for a reason.
- There's no reason to do `$(event.target).attr('id')`, just use `event.target.id` directly.
- If the `div` may contain other elements (`span`s, `em`s, `p`s, etc.), note that `event.target` may not be the `div`, it may be a descendant element of the `div`. `this` will always be the `div`, though (jQuery sees to that), so:

  ```
  $("#d22").click(goToEdit);
  function goToEdit(event) {
      tree.selectItem(this.id.substring(1));
      btnMyButton_onclick();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a reference to the element to the function.

```
 ... onclick="goToEdit(this);">
```

and

```
function goToEdit(element)
    {
       tree.selectItem($(element).attr('id'));
       btnMyButton_onclick();
    }
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/SwUuE/4/

Comment: Thanks Rick it Helped me !

Answer (score 0):

HTML name and id tokens must begin with a letter. You have `id="22"`. Maybe it causes inconsistency between browsers. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: Yes and no. :-) As of HTML5, that ID is [fine *for HTML and the DOM*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), and here the spec is just documenting existing behavior (browsers have no problem with `document.getElementById("22")`). CSS still requires that it [start with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: ...and I'm pleased to see that all the browsers I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9) correctly threw an error on `document.querySelector("#22")` in standards mode; Chrome and Firefox also throw an error in quirks mode, whereas Opera tolerated the invalid CSS `id` and IE9 reported that it didn't have `querySelector` at all. So it'll depend on what `tree.selectItem` does and whether it uses that `id` value in a DOM selection. Tests: [Standards](http://jsbin.com/acedug) | [Quirks](http://jsbin.com/acedug/2)

Answer (score 0):

By definition div is used to divide your page into different sections.
Use anchor or input with type button tag instead

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can remove "onclick" from your html

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div id="22" class="otherClass">Title</div>
    <div class="parent">Other title</div>
</div>
```

And then try something like this

```
$('#22').on('click', function (e) {
    your code
});
```

**But** if your div id="22" will be added dynamically your should use something like this

```
$('parent').on('click', '#22', function (e) {
    your code
});
```

where 'parent' - static element already existed in document before click

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing same problem , but this code helped me.

I was testing on Mozilla Firefox and Chrome, it worked on both.

```
<input type="button" onclick="return goBack();" class="btn btn-warning cancel" value=" Cancel" style="color:white" />

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```