# .click() execute does not work in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I have this simple piece of code that for some reason works on all browsers except for Mozilla.

This is my HTML:

```
<img src="{{#asset}}menu_button.svg{{/asset}}" id="menu_button"></img>
<img src="{{#asset}}exit.svg{{/asset}}" id="exit"></img>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_button").click(function(event){
    show();      
    });
    $("#exit").click(function(event){
    hide();      
    });
});   

function show(element){
      event.preventDefault();
    $('#background_mobile_portrait').addClass('blur');
    $('#background_mobile_landscape').addClass('blur');
    $('.links').css('opacity', '1');
    $('#menu_button').css('opacity', '0');
    $('#exit').css('opacity', '1').css('z-index', '999');

}        


function hide(){
      event.preventDefault();
         $('#background_mobile_portrait').removeClass('blur');
         $('#background_mobile_landscape').removeClass('blur');
         $('.links').css('opacity', '0');
         $('#exit').css('opacity', '0').css('z-index', '-1');
         $('#menu_button').css('opacity', '1');
      }
```

When clicking on the image in Firefox, nothing happens. All other browsers works like a charm.
I have been following this post that refer to problems with  onclick execution:
[Div onclick event not called in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208944/div-onclick-event-not-called-in-mozilla)

I have applied the changes suggested but with no success.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matan

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: code looks good, have you tried using `on('click')`?

Comment: I think you wanted the `javascript` tag, not `java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not passing on the `event` object to the function.

It works in IE and chrome because they define a `window.event`. Firefox does not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_button").click(function(event){
        show(event);      
    });
    $("#exit").click(function(event){
        hide(event);      
    });
});
```

and then define the first parameter to each function to receive the `event` object.

```
function show(event) {
    // ...
}

function hide(event) {
    // ...
}
```

---

And FYI, you could do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_button").click(show);
    $("#exit").click(hide);
});
```

Now `this` will be your element, and the first parameter will receive `event`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't solve it, but in any case the image tag should be closed with a /> (or just.  >) see [How to close <img> tag properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly)

Comment: HTML5 style conventions say all "void" tags (e.g., `<br>`, `<tr>`, `<img>`) should be closed without a slash. A really good place to read up on code styling conventions for HTML, JavaScript, and CSS is [the code guide](http://mdo.github.io/code-guide/) written by mdo, one of the main contributors to the twitter bootstrap project.